# Ice Cube Gem: Recurring Emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ice-cube

Does anyone have an understanding of the `ice_cube` gem API? I'm trying to use it for sending reoccurring emails and I'm not sure if I understand if thats a valid use case for it or not. Does anyone have any examples? I can't find any anywhere. The existing documentations and tutorials are ambiguous and don't actually show an example of a repeating process taking place (like sending emails, deleting objects from a database, etc.). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ice-cube itself isn't designed for this purpose. You'll want to use a processing tool like [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) that actually runs tasks you create. ice-cube is a library tools like Sidekiq use to help with configuration, you don't need to use it directly.

If you're sending mails periodically e.g. every week, add a plugin like [sidekiq-scheduler](https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler).

You could also just set up a cron job to send off mails according to a schedule, ifyour needs are moderate.

Comment: So when you have recurring events in ice cube, does that mean that a new event object will be created say, every day if it is scheduled to run every day?

Comment: It won't create events or run them. It's just a library to help you setup a schedule and ask questions like "when should the next event occur?". You can think of it as a kind of mini-database designed just for schedules. For typical email activity, most people would use a processor tool like Sidekiq or just a cron job.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!